# how to autotrigger prev and next button when using tabs in angular material

Tags: javascript, angular-material

How to automatically trigger the prev and next button when window is resized? here is my html

```
<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="tabsdemoDynamicTabs" layout="column" ng-app="MyApp">
    <md-content class="md-padding">
        <md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex" md-border-bottom="" md-autoselect="">
            <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-disabled="tab.disabled" label="@{{tab.title}}">
                <div class="demo-tab tab@{{$index%4}}" style="padding: 25px; text-align: center;">
                    <div ng-bind="tab.content"></div>
                </div>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

and here is the javascript

```
    'use strict';       
    var tabs = [
          { title: 'One', content: "Tabs will become paginated if there isn't enough room for them."},
          { title: 'Two', content: "You can swipe left and right on a mobile device to change tabs."},
          { title: 'Three', content: "You can bind the selected tab via the selected attribute on the md-tabs element."},
          { title: 'Four', content: "If you set the selected tab binding to -1, it will leave no tab selected."},
          { title: 'Five', content: "If you remove a tab, it will try to select a new one."},
          { title: 'Six', content: "There's an ink bar that follows the selected tab, you can turn it off if you want."},
          { title: 'Seven', content: "If you set ng-disabled on a tab, it becomes unselectable. If the currently selected tab becomes disabled, it will try to select the next tab."},
          { title: 'Eight', content: "If you look at the source, you're using tabs to look at a demo for tabs. Recursion!"},
          { title: 'Nine', content: "If you set md-theme=\"green\" on the md-tabs element, you'll get green tabs."},
          { title: 'Ten', content: "If you're still reading this, you should just go check out the API docs for tabs!"}
        ],
        selected = null,
        previous = null;
    $scope.tabs = tabs;
    $scope.selectedIndex = 2;
    $scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function(current, old){
      previous = selected;
      selected = tabs[current];
      if ( old + 1 && (old != current)) $log.debug('Goodbye ' + previous.title + '!');
      if ( current + 1 )                $log.debug('Hello ' + selected.title + '!');
    });
```

if possible, I want to minimise the custom js and css.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Angular Material are you using?  This should happen automatically on resize in the latest version (0.10.0).

Comment: it's the latest. 0.10.0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need the answer but for others who have spent hours could use the following.

Reverting back to angular 1.3.15 works with angular material 0.10.0 . angular 1.4.3 seems to have an issue. Issue is that the md-prev-button and md-next-button aren't getting rendered.